# Can PaPiRus serve as normal display for Raspberry Pi? (ePaper / eInk Screen HAT)

Tags: display, eink

Can [PaPiRus](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/pisupply/papirus-the-epaper-screen-hat-for-your-raspberry-p) - ePaper / eInk Screen HAT for Raspberry Pi - work as normal default display? I would be happy to see terminal when Linux is booting and later login and use terminal. Starting X would be awesome, but to my usecase terminal (eventually with framebuffer graphics) would be sufficient.

How to configure it to work like that?

For example to run and see terminal, and eventually display sth using framebuffer like with `fbi` framebuffer picture viewer.

Note: I aim to use it for special application with little status data with low refresh rate. I have already a couple if e-Ink devices so I am aware of their capabilities, pros and cons. They are awesome for displaying pdfs, of status boards with low refreshrate.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you want to display. Your note makes it sound like you aren't looking for something that will involve displaying the desktop, which is good. It certainly doesn't have a refresh rate capable of doing so in a reasonable fashion. I expect it to be slow, even for terminal application use.

These kinds of screens excel at sign style displays. If you want to display a picture (that doesn't change quickly), text (like a sign or an ereader), or an application that displays like an alarm clock or status indicator, the PaPiRus should work very well.

Comment: I'd love to display like any other framebuffer screen including booting - i.e. see terminal when system is booting, login prompt, login, use terminal (e.g. dialog, scripts, vim) and eventually framebuffer (e.g. display picture with `fbi`), again I worked with eink screens and I kniw how their refreshrate  behaves, and I have applications in mind compatible with their capabilities.

Comment: If you're aware of the refresh limitations, then the screen should work fairly well. I haven't been able to find any real reviews about it yet.